# How does uber appz track realtime?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, uber-api

I just want to ask how does the uber appz track realtime ?.Do they request to server every 1 second to updates the position of car so that the car moves?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

All of their realtime/dispatch systems are built on [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and [Redis.](http://redis.io/)

Thats a very general idea of waht they do for the real time tracking, theres pretty few info about this.

You can find more in this answer, posted by a Software Engineer of uber in QUORA:

http://www.quora.com/What-technology-does-Uber-use